# Modifying nouns with phrase + 的

Tags: grammar

We were discussing [this](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Modifying_nouns_with_phrase_%2B_%22de%22) topic in the class yesterday and had a few difficulties understanding it. The main problem was to understand when the sentence / phrase is referred to a regular action or to the action in the past. Could this be figured out without additional time markers?

For example, from these sentences: 
去北京的火车 or 妈妈做的菜

Comment: Similar questions had been asked many times. Here is one of them:   http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22204/why-no-%e7%9a%84-in-this-sentence/22206#22206  To check if your question had been asked in the past, you can type key words in the search Q&A box on the upper right corner of the page.

Comment: @TangHo Of course I searched for similar questions before posting mine. I didn't see the answer to my question in the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Modifying nouns with phrase + 的

A [phrase + 'adjective suffix 的'] is an 'adjective phrase'. It functions as an adjective for the noun. If there is a [clause +'adjective suffix 的'], then it is an 'adjective clause'

的 can also be a 'possessive' but that's another topic.

> The main problem was to understand when the sentence / phrase is referred to a regular action or to the action in the past.  Could this be figured out without additional time markers?

May be this can help: [How do you specify past tense for 是?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22011/how-do-you-specify-past-tense-for-%e6%98%af)

So, the answer is, " no, you can't figure out the action is in the past or present without additional time markers, but you don't need to"

Answer (score 1):

An explicit time marker is always required.  There is no exception. But sometime it depends on the context, even without a time marker.

```
到达了北京的火车
The train that reached Beijing

这都是妈妈做的菜
All this food are cooked by mum.
```

Comment: "An explicit time marker is always required."  I assume you mean, *if you want to specify the time* (or aspect).  Otherwise, an explicit time marker is not required for the phrase to be grammatical.