# How to negate an adjective in the past?

Tags: adjectives, past-tense, negation

How can I negate an adjective in the past?

For example:
这是红色的。It is red. 
这不是红色的。It's not red.

How could I say 'It was not red'? I read somewhere that 没有 only negates action verbs. If that's true, would the sentence in the past be the same (apart from time expressions) as the present?

Comment: past time might be indicated by 曾、曾经 or other adverb like 以前：曾经（以前）不是红色的，Does "it was not red" imply "now it is red"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do you specify past tense for 是?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22011/how-do-you-specify-past-tense-for-%e6%98%af/22016#22016)

From my answer:

*You have to remember, unlike in English, we do not have past tense for verbs in Chinese grammar. Both "is" and "was" is written as "是" in Chinese.*

Answer (score 1):

You can say "它以前不是红色的". But it can imply somehow "它现在是红色的"。